# Switch to control which way a current goes

Tags: switches, dc

I want an switch that directs a DC current to a circuit based on whether an I/O pin sends a voltage or not. What components do I need to make this switch? Here is the schematic: [image: schematic]

Comment: Would you be more specific? Like draw a schematic what you want to control. Otherwise we don't know whether to suggest an analog mux or a 10A contactor relay. Will the current from the IO pin itself be enough to drive the circuit? You also have not accepted any answer to your previous question, if they are not good enough for accepting then work on improving them.

Comment: Is V2 the supply used to drive the circuits Circuit 1 and Circuit 2? Is the driving of the two  circuits mutually exclusive i.e. when Circuit 2 is driven Circuit 1 is off? What load do the two circuits present to the supply? Where is the schematic? Lots of missing details.

Comment: yes, V2 is the supply used to drive the circuits and yes, the circuits are mutually exclusive

Comment: Also, V2 is 5v, not 1v.

Answer (score 1):

An SPDT relay and a freewheeling diode would suffice.

[image]

Comment: Could be overkill for a small load. OP needs to specify what the load is to sensibly answer the question.

Comment: @mhaselup, I'm with you but I thought my answer would elicit a response from the OP that could point in the right direction. Many thanks.